# Duplicates removing

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete duplicate records from a SQL table without a primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985384/delete-duplicate-records-from-a-sql-table-without-a-primary-key)

I have data:

```
SELECT
          a
        , b
    FROM 
    (
        select a = 1, b = 30
        union all 
        select a = 2, b = 50
        union all 
        select a = 3, b = 50
        union all 
        select a = 4, b = 50
        union all 
        select a = 5, b = 60
    ) t
```

I have to get output (next (order by **a**) dublicate records should be excluded from result set):

```
a           b
----------- -----------
1           30
2           50
3           50  -- should be excluded
4           50  -- should be excluded
5           60
```

Comment: So the question is more complicated than `select min(a), b
from ...
group by b`? -- because that would work with your example data

Comment: @antlersoft it is good enough. I have: a is int and b is uniqueidentifier, so it will work too. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
          min(a) as a
        , b
    FROM 
    (
        select a = 1, b = 30
        union all 
        select a = 2, b = 50
        union all 
        select a = 3, b = 50
        union all 
        select a = 4, b = 50
        union all 
        select a = 5, b = 60
    ) t
GROUP BY b    
ORDER BY a
```

Comment: What if a had a non-numeric entry?

Comment: @P.R - You should still be able to use `min()`.

Comment: it crashes and says that it wasn't able to convert to number (I tried it on MS)

Comment: @P.R - what data type did you use? What did you test? You got to have the same data type for all values in a column.

Answer (score 1):

In oracle I was able to do this using a group by clause, you should be able to do similar.

```
select min(a), b
 from (select 1 a, 30 b
        from dual
      union all
      select 2 a, 50 b
        from dual
      union all
      select 3 a, 50 b
        from dual
      union all
      select 4 a, 50 b
        from dual
      union all
      select 5 a, 60 b from dual)
group by b;
```

edit: looks like someone else came up with a MS sql solution, I'll leave this here for posterity though.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with a simple `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
      a
    , b
INTO #tmp
FROM

(
    select a = 1, b = 30
    union all 
    select a = 2, b = 50
    union all 
    select a = 3, b = 50
    union all 
    select a = 4, b = 50
    union all 
    select a = 5, b = 60
) t


SELECT DISTINCT MIN(a) AS a,b
FROM #tmp
GROUP BY b
ORDER BY a
```

Comment: The distinct won't do anythin as you are grouping by b and usin an aggegate on a, each row would already be gaurunteed to be distinct.