# sql : Delete all records except the 2 most recent for each combination(channel/cdn/mediaplaylist)

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the sql query to delete all records except the 2 most recent for each combination (channel/cdn/mediaplaylist).

For example, I have the following table:

```
channel       cdn        mediaplaylist      response    date

channel1      cdn1       mediaplaylist1     12          2015-02-09 10:40:00
channel2      cdn2       mediaplaylist2     19          2015-02-09 10:41:00   
channel3      cdn3       mediaplaylist3     16          2015-02-09 10:42:00
channel1      cdn1       mediaplaylist1     20          2015-02-09 10:43:00
channel1      cdn1       mediaplaylist1     57          2015-02-09 10:46:00
channel2      cdn2       mediaplaylist2     83          2015-02-09 10:47:00    
channel3      cdn3       mediaplaylist3     37          2015-02-09 10:48:00
channel1      cdn1       mediaplaylist1     43          2015-02-09 10:49:00
channel1      cdn1       mediaplaylist1     33          2015-02-09 10:50:00
channel2      cdn2       mediaplaylist2     79          2015-02-09 10:51:00    
channel3      cdn3       mediaplaylist3     19          2015-02-09 10:52:00
channel1      cdn1       mediaplaylist1     13          2015-02-09 10:53:00
```

I would like to get the following result :

```
channel       cdn        mediaplaylist      response    date

channel1      cdn1       mediaplaylist1     12          2015-02-09 10:40:00
channel1      cdn1       mediaplaylist1     20          2015-02-09 10:43:00
channel2      cdn2       mediaplaylist2     19          2015-02-09 10:41:00
channel2      cdn2       mediaplaylist2     83          2015-02-09 10:47:00
channel3      cdn3       mediaplaylist3     16          2015-02-09 10:42:00
channel3      cdn3       mediaplaylist3     37          2015-02-09 10:48:00
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: Please learn to format your questions after 12 posts.

Comment: Actually i'm writing a php script and i would like to get the result from mysql

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicates removing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447675/duplicates-removing)

Answer (score 3):

With SQL-Server it is easy, just use a CTE and a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By channel, cdn, mediaplaylist 
                                Order By date DESC), 
           c.*  -- select all columns for debugging purposes
    FROM dbo.Channels c
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 2
```

I like common-table-expressions since they allow to see what i'm going to delete. Therefore you just need to replace `DELETE` with `SELECT *`.

Comment: You should not delete from the CTE, you should delete from the table while filtering using the CTE

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou: this will delete from the table `Channels`. I have presumed that table-name from the description. You can use this syntax if you don't use a `JOIN` in the CTE.

Comment: Please , is it possible to introduce your sql code in a php script? i would like to get the result from mysql database.

Comment: Do you have any solution with mysql?

Comment: @lipdjo: MySql doesn't support ranking functions. I'm afraid i have no solution for MySql right now.

Comment: If I add a Where clause to Channels, will it still have to partition the entire table or will it use the Where clause first then do the partition?

Comment: @rod: if you add the where to the inner query/cte you will get a different result since the filter is applied first.

Answer (score 0):

The following query enumerates the rows as you have them:

```
select f.*,
       (@rn := if(@ccp = concat_ws(':', channel, cdn, mediaplaylist), @rn + 1,
                  if(@ccp := concat_ws(':', channel, cdn, mediaplaylist), 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as seqnum
from following f cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @ccp := '') vars
order by channel, cdn, mediaplaylist, date desc;
```

You want the values where `seqnum` is 1 or 2.

You can put this in a `delete`:

delete f
    from following f join
         (select f.*,
                 (@rn := if(@ccp = concat_ws(':', channel, cdn, mediaplaylist), @rn + 1,
                            if(@ccp := concat_ws(':', channel, cdn, mediaplaylist), 1, 1)
                           )
                 ) as seqnum
          from following f cross join
               (select @rn := 0, @ccp := '') vars
          order by channel, cdn, mediaplaylist, date desc
         ) ccp
         on f.channel = ccp.channel and f.cdn = ccp.cdn and f.mediaplaylist = cdn.mediaplaylist
    where seqnum < 3;