# Delete records from SQL table without having PK

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table named itemorder with: `userID`, `itemID`, `date`, `status`, `notes` in my `MYSQL DB`.
The PK of the table is `userID, itemID`

I need to write an SQL query that will delete all rows who are 2 days old and status = 2.
(this sql query will run in my server once a day).

I've written the following sql query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM itemorder 
WHERE
  statusOrder=2
  AND statusDate< (SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY))
```

the query returns all rows who are match to condition. however if i change the `SELECT *` to `DELETE` it doesn't work.

here is the code

```
DELETE
FROM itemorder 
WHERE
  statusOrder=2
  AND statusDate<(SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY))
```

it says: `Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Query Editor and reconnect.`

from the error i understood that i can not delete as the query `WHERE` doesn't identify each rows by it's PK. what can i do?
I read the topic [Delete duplicate records from a SQL table without a primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985384/delete-duplicate-records-from-a-sql-table-without-a-primary-key) however still couldn't figure how to change my `SELECT` to `DELETE`.

Comment: What happens when you go to `Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Query Editor` ? Do you see something like `disable safe mode` ?

Comment: Can you add the exact SQL you tested the Delete with?

Comment: willOEM, same as mentioned just insted of select *, i wrote delete

Comment: try "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;" ?

Comment: Could you provide the table structure and some sample data to debug your SQL query? You can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE ITEMORDER;` to output the create table.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
DELETE FROM itemorder WHERE statusOrder=2 AND datediff(now(), statusDate) > 2
```

It should work

Comment: Ok re-updated, in fact it was the "AS" clause, now it works for me, just tested it, let me know if it works for you!

Comment: nop.. same error... are u sure that in ur test u set the PK right?

Comment: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Query Editor and reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a workaround:

```
DELETE
FROM itemorder 
WHERE UserID & '-' & ItemID in (
SELECT UserID & '-' & ItemID FROM itemorder
WHERE statusOrder=2 AND statusDate<(SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY))
)
```

Comment: what is the syntax for "YourPK " ? i wrote UserID and itemID. but it doesnt work. it says Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: MySQL apparently does not support where (col1, col2) in (select col1, col2...), so you would have to use something like: where userID & '-' & itemID in (select userID & '-' & itemID... FROM itemorder...) - have edited post

Comment: this gives another error Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'itemorder' for update in FROM clause

Comment: You're right - just tried in SQL Workbench. You will just have to disable safe update mode. (In SQL Workbench it's Edit/Preferences/SQL Editor - clear "Safe Updates" in Query Editor section and reconnect to your database.) You can then run almost any of the delete scripts on this page...

Answer (score 0):

TRY this:
`DELETE FROM ITEMORDER WHERE status = 2 AND status <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY);`

[DEMO SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e09f6/2)

Comment: @ronnjack could you let me know if this works for you or not?