# Oracle: Why I cannot rely on ROWNUM in a delete clause

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

I have a such statement:

```
SELECT MIN(ROWNUM) FROM my_table
GROUP BY NAME 
HAVING COUNT(NAME) > 1);
```

This statement gives me the `rownum` of the first duplicate, but when transform this statement into `DELETE` it just delete everything. Why does it happen so?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because ROWNUM is a pseudo column which implies that they do not exist physically. You can better use `rowid` to delete the records.

To remove the duplicates you can try like this:

```
DELETE FROM mytable a
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM mytable b
              WHERE a.id = b.id
              AND a.name = b.name
              AND a.rowid > b.rowid )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `rownum` to delete duplicate records makes not much sense. If you need to delete duplicate rows, leaving only one row for each value of `name`, try the following:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
  WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT ID
                    FROM (SELECT ROWID ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                             (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) numRows FROM mytable
                         )
                   WHERE numRows > 1)
```

By adding further columns in `ORDER BY` clause, you can choice to delete the record with greatest/smallest `ID`, or some other field.