# delete duplicate rows SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, duplicates

i have column and rows in my table as below

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
-----------------------
A     1     100   AA
B     2     200   BB
B     1     100   AA
A     2     200   BB
```

col2, col3 and col4 have duplicate rows, but not in col1. i want the final result is

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
-----------------------
A     1     100   AA
B     2     200   BB
```

i've tried this queries, but not Working

```
DELETE aliasName FROM 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3,col4 ORDER BY col1
    ) AS rowNumber FROM Table) aliasName
WHERE rowNumber > 1
```

if i remove the PARTITION BY col1, the result is

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
-----------------------
A     1     100   AA
A     2     200   BB
```

---

this my real table result is

```
JSP/14/06/2017/1810759183   SRK/14/06/2017/1265996087   JS_43345.43556  BB  20000   1
JSP/14/06/2017/800205939    SRK/14/06/2017/2089009939   JS_43345.43556  BB  20000   1
```

Comment: How do you know which value in `col1` to keep?  In your sample data, why are you retaining the first and second rows instead of the third and fourth rows?

Comment: that data is made by looping in my program, there are 3 times looping before it send to database

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  All 4 rows of data in your question are unique, which means you are actively excluding the 3rd and 4th rows without explaining why.  What criteria is used to pick the first 2 rows to keep instead of the second 2 rows?

Comment: yeah sir, i have i more column is unique that not i including here. total column is 5th..i just need rows of the col1 to keep col2,col3 and col4 together, but not have duplicates in the col1. i hope you understand what i am saying sir

Comment: What you are asking for makes no sense.  **All 4 rows in your question are unique** regardless of the 5th column you have just mentioned.

Comment: can you help me sir? just skip the criteria that makes you confused, i just need that col1 have no duplicate rows sir

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985384/delete-duplicate-records-from-a-sql-table-without-a-primary-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
DELETE aliasName FROM 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
       ORDER BY col1
    ) AS rowNumber FROM inp) aliasName
WHERE rowNumber%2 = 0
```

Comment: thanks for the queries, btw still not working.. col1 have no duplicates with that query, but col2,col3 and col4 have duplicate

Comment: DELETE aliasName FROM 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by col1
       order BY col1
    ) AS rowNumber FROM inp) aliasName
WHERE rowNumber > 1

Comment: what's ur result now ?

Comment: SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by col1 order BY col1 ) AS rowNumber FROM TABLE        can u show me the output of this query

Comment: wait sir, on going

Comment: col1  col2  col3  col4
-----------------------
A     1     100   AA
B     1     100   AA

Comment: SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by col1 order BY col1 ) AS rowNumber FROM TABLE            what about this one

Comment: where is the delete statement sir?

Comment: can u jst execute this query and show mw the output of your rowNumber column

Comment: col1                 col2                 col3                 col4        rowNumber
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------
A                    1                    100                  AA                   1
A                    2                    200                  BB                   2
B                    2                    200                  BB                   1
B                    1                    100                  AA                   2    are u getting this output

Comment: where i can send you the picture? i take a screenshot for the result sir

Comment: add it in your question

Comment: A 1 100 AA                                       1
A 2 200 BB                                       2
B 2 200 BB                                       1
B 1 100 AA                                       2

Comment: ya then this query will work for sure 

DELETE aliasName FROM 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1
    ) AS rowNumber FROM inp) aliasName
WHERE rowNumber > 1

Comment: col1                 col2                 col3                 col4
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
A                    1                    100                  AA
B                    2                    200                  BB

this is the output u expecting right ?

Comment: oh my God! you're save my life sir!! thank you very very much for helping me a lot.. it's working know!

Comment: i am newly join on here, i dont know to mark it as useful sir.. i just wanna say thank you

Comment: pls click the up arrow  on the left side of my answer

Comment: @Nithin, oopss!! that still not working on my real table.. idk why it just working on my temporary table i've made it

Comment: the result for my real table is still 

a  1  100  AA
b  1  100  AA