# Delete duplicate entries keeping one entry of each if id column not available

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried,

```
delete from Student where FirstName in
(
    select FirstName  from
    (
     select FirstName,
     row_number() over(partition by FirstName order by FirstName) as rn
     from Student
    ) Student
    WHERE rn > 1
);
```

but its deleting both duplicate records.
please correct my query.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using!

Comment: have table primary key?

Comment: MS   SQL  SERVER........

Comment: No primary key and any id column. all columns are varchar type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985384/delete-duplicate-records-from-a-sql-table-without-a-primary-key

Comment: You are correctly identifying duplicates, and only one of each, in the inner `select`s. However, the `delete` statement couldn't care less how many duplicates you have, and will delete anything that has a match on `FirstName`.

Comment: Not working for my case @matt

Comment: The simplest solution is to add a primary key to your table. That will save you problems in the future as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)

```
    WITH MyCTE 
    AS
    (
       SELECT [FirstName], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName ORDER BY FirstName) RN
       FROM Student
    )
    DELETE FROM MyCTE WHERE RN > 1;
    SELECT * FROM Students;
```

Comment: I think you need ";" before WITH

Answer (score 0):

You're deleting based on FirstName hence it's deleting all the records from your table, try like this will do.

[Live Demo](http://rextester.com/NOLA15686)

```
WITH StudentCte
As
(
SELECT FirstName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by FirstName ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as RowNum
FROM Student
)

DELETE FROM StudentCte WHERE RowNum > 1;

SELECT * 
From Student;
```